# Array syntax vs. pointer syntax in C function parameters

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, parameters

I understand how arrays decay to pointers. I understand that, for the compiler, this:

```
void foo(int *arg1);
```

is 100% equivalent to this:

```
void foo(int arg1[]);
```

Should one style be preferred over the other? I want to be consistent, but I'm having a hard time justifying either decision.

Although `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)` are the same, the former seems to be much more common (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: If your goal is consistency, you should use the asterisk, since that's consistent with normal (non-parameter) declarations.  The other syntax should die, it causes nothing but confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend **against** using the `[]` syntax for function parameters.

The one argument in favour of using `[]` is that it implies, in a self-documenting way, that the pointer is expected to point to more than one thing. For example:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
double average(int vals[], int n)
```

But then why is `char *` always used for strings rather than `char []`? I'd rather be consistent and always use `*`.

Some people like to `const` everything they possibly can, including pass-by-value parameters. The syntax for that when using `[]` (available only in C99) is less intuitive and probably less well-known:

`const char *const *const words` vs. `const char *const words[const]`

Although I do consider that final `const` to be overkill, in any case.

Furthermore, the way that arrays *decay* is not completely intuitive. In particular, it is [**not** applied recursively](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr#pass2dary) (`char words[][]` doesn't work). Especially when you start throwing in more indirection, the `[]` syntax just causes confusion. IMO it is better to always use pointer syntax rather than pretending that an array is passed as an argument.

More information: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr#aryptrparam.

Comment: is it more safe to use[] this syntax then * one?

Comment: There is absolutely no difference to the compiler whether you use an array or a pointer as a function parameter—it will end up being a pointer either way, and consequently be subject to "pointer hazards".

Answer (score 3):

Except for `char*`, I use `Type array[N]`, where N is some number or a defined constant, when the passed item conceptually is an array (i.e., it contains N>1 elements), `Type * pointer` when the passed item is a pointer to exactly one object.

I tend to use `std::vector` if the array is of a variable size. C99's concept of variable sized arrays is not available in C++.

Comment: But the `N` is silently ignored, which I find misleading.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You are correct; the compiler does ignore it. However, you aren't just writing for the compiler, you are also writing for the human user of your code. That arrays decay into pointers is one of the biggest flaws in C/C++ from the perspective of a scientific programmer. There is no reason to kowtow to that huge gaping flaw.

Comment: What if you had a pointer to an array of strings (i.e. char pointer for the string, pointer to char pointer for words, pointer to pointer to char pointer to allow the function to write to it)? `char *(*words[])`? IMO `char ***words` looks better and is easier to take in at a glance. I suppose, though, that this kind of thing is more common in C (which I am primarily interested in) than C++, though.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yes, you're writing for the human user, which is why I don't like to imply that the `N` actually means something.