# What is the difference with pointer and array as parameters?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is there any major difference between them? To me it looks the same...and according to some googling it seems the same as well..Just wanna confirm it here..

```
void getAnything(int arr [])
{
    arr[0] = 2;
}
```

versus

```
void getAnything(int *arr)
{
    arr[0] = 2;
}
```

main

```
int main()
{
    int arr [1];
    getAnything(arr);
}
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. As a parameter declaration (and *only* as a parameter declaration), `int arr []` really means `int *arr`. There are no parameters of array type. An expression of array type is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Which is why `sizeof arr` inside the function gives you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array; you have to track that yourself. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it applies to C++ as well as to C.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127625/array-syntax-vs-pointer-syntax-in-c-function-parameters

Comment: You could have just compiled the code and the compiler would have stated that the functions are the same, thus an error would have been emitted.  http://ideone.com/xrtFYW

Answer (score 1):

It is the same. In fact, i you would have something like

```
void getAnything(int arr [10])
{
    arr[0] = 2;
}
```

would also be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are precisely equivalent:

> `[C++11: 8.3.5/5]:` *[..]* After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`,” respectively. *[..]*

It's quite confusing because it means that your argument need not actually have anything to do with arrays whatsoever, but there you go; thanks, C! It also helps to encourage the myth that "arrays are pointers", sadly.

All of the following:

```
void foo(int[]   x);
void foo(int[5]  x);
void foo(int[42] x);
```

actually mean this:

```
void foo(int* x);
```